# Numpy multiplication of 3d arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have 2 arrays I want to multiply. The first one has dimensions 1000x2x1 the other one 1000x1x2. I want the result to have dimension 1000x2x2. This could be easily achieved by looping over the arrays 1000 times but that would be very inefficient.

How can I accomplish this without for loop?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a **[mcve]**? For a minimal example you can replace `1000` with (for example) `10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the `*` operator between the two arrays. For more information, see [numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

```
arr1 = np.random.rand(1000, 2, 1)
arr2 = np.random.rand(1000, 1, 2)
arr3 = arr1 * arr2 
print(arr3.shape) #(1000, 2, 2)
```